# How to update composer 1.6.3 to latest version 2.0.4?

Tags: updates, laravel, composer

I have tried to update my existing composer version in ubuntu.

and I try to check the version but ubuntu say package not found.

Then I again try `sudo apt install composer` to install composer.

Now when I checked the composer's version. It shows 1.6.3 and if I try `/home/alok/composer.phar` then the composer's version is 2.0.4.

I am confused. What should I do?

Please help me to solve this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the old `composer` (the one in the repros):

```
sudo apt remove composer
```

There will remain a directory with preferences in your home folder. Move that out of the way:

```
mv ~/.composer ~/was-composer
```

Then, execute the four commands at the top of this page: https://getcomposer.org/download/

You now have a local version that you can run with `php composer.phar`. To make it global, first make it executable, then copy it to a directory that lies on your $PATH:

```
chmod +x composer.phar
sudo mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer
```

Now you can do `composer require...` etc., from any directory.

Answer (score 2):

In your terminal type:

```
composer self-update
```

or

```
composer selfupdate
```

It will be updated to the latest version.

Comment: This should be the correct answer, easy and straight forward

Comment: This isn't working on v1.6.3 `Command "self-update" is not defined.`